# Visual Studio 2022 - Errors and warnings - can't change Warning level

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (64-bit) - 17.2.2. When I change project properties for a `.NET 6` project I cant change `Errors and warnings` - `Warning level`. My current level is `6 - Warnings from C# 10`

I'm trying to set this to either `7 - Warnings from C# 11` or `9999 - All warnings`. What happens is I can set the value but the value is restored to `6 - Warnings from C# 10`.

[image]

Setting other values work as expected.

Warning Level:

Specifies the level to display for compiler warnings. Higher levels produce more warnings, and include all warnings from lower levels.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-page-project-designer-csharp?view=vs-2022#errors-and-warnings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#warninglevel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a GUI bug. Even if the value is restored to `6 - Warnings from C# 10` in Visual Studio the `.csproj` file still gets modified if I press the save button with a value like `<WarningLevel>9999</WarningLevel>`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ogglas, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to disable some of the Visual Studio 2022 warnings, in particular the ones that warns about a possible null value when declaring a class.

After several searches I haven't found a correct way to do it properly, I'm trying to generate noise in the code and keep the solution as clear as possible.

In this case I want to disable `CS8618` and `CS8601`, if possible at IDE level, or in case it has to be at project level, set some directive in a file that can be shared to have the same configuration at team level.

The closest thing has been Microsoft's guide [How to: Suppress compiler warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2022), but I want to go a little further and find out if there is a more global and cleaner solution.